# Terraform CustomScriptExtension reports unable to download files

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

G'day,

I am running a Terraform extension - CustomScriptExtension. However it reports the error that it is unable to load the files.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "tf-vm-grpprd-ad-ext-install-addom" {
  count                      = "${var.count_ad_vm}"
  name                       = "${var.ad_base_hostname}${format("%02d",count.index+1)}-CSE"
  location                   = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-grpprd-core.location}"
  resource_group_name        = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-grpprd-core.name}"
  virtual_machine_name       = "${var.ad_base_hostname}${format("%02d",count.index+1)}"
  publisher                  = "${var.extension_publisher_ad}"
  type                       = "${var.extension_type_customerscriptextension}"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = "true"
  type_handler_version       = "${var.extension_version_customscriptextension}"
  depends_on                 = ["azurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad"]
   settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "fileUris": ["https://blackbeltteam.visualstudio.com/blackbeltteam/_git/groupsprod/scripts/Install_AD_Components.ps1"],
        "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe pwd",
        "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe ls",
        "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -NoProfile -NonInteractive -File Install_AD_Components.ps1"
    }
SETTINGS
}
```

I get the error message as below:

```
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0860444Z [1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mCode="VMExtensionProvisioningError" Message="VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'grpprdad02-CSE'. Error message: \"Failed to download all specified files. Exiting. Error Message: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.\"."[0m
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0860808Z 
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0861339Z [0m  on ad.tf line 250, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "tf-vm-grpprd-ad-ext-install-addom":
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0861901Z  250: resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "tf-vm-grpprd-ad-ext-install-addom" [4m{[0m
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0862336Z [0m
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0862897Z [0m[0m
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0894295Z [31m
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0895064Z [1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mCode="VMExtensionProvisioningError" Message="VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'grpprdad01-CSE'. Error message: \"Failed to download all specified files. Exiting. Error Message: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.\"."[0m
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0895600Z 
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0896889Z [0m  on ad.tf line 250, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "tf-vm-grpprd-ad-ext-install-addom":
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0897664Z  250: resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "tf-vm-grpprd-ad-ext-install-addom" [4m{[0m
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0898223Z [0m
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0898695Z [0m[0m
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0943083Z [31m
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0944168Z [1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mcompute.VirtualMachineExtensionsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: Code="ParentResourceNotFound" Message="Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'grpprdaos01' not found."[0m
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0944773Z 
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0945288Z [0m  on aos.tf line 240, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "tf-vm-grpprd-aos-ext-join-ad":
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0945858Z  240: resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "tf-vm-grpprd-aos-ext-join-ad" [4m{[0m
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0946979Z [0m
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0947787Z [0m[0m
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0990513Z [31m
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0991014Z [1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mcompute.VirtualMachineExtensionsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: Code="ParentResourceNotFound" Message="Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'grpprdaos02' not found."[0m
2019-07-31T01:17:20.0991108Z 
2019-07-31T01:17:20.1002906Z [0m  on aos.tf line 240, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "tf-vm-grpprd-aos-ext-join-ad":
2019-07-31T01:17:20.1003501Z  240: resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "tf-vm-grpprd-aos-ext-join-ad" [4m{[0m
```

It does not indicate which command it failed to execute, where it is running etc, how can I understand what is causing the grief.

Comment: I was unwell, still recovering but I would check it out now.

Comment: Hope you get to feeling better soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be the resource is not found when you access the URI `https://blackbeltteam.visualstudio.com/blackbeltteam/_git/groupsprod/scripts/Install_AD_Components.ps1`. The script location can be anywhere, as long as the VM can route to that endpoint, such as GitHub or an internal file server.

You could ensure the resources could be retrieved by the file Uri in the `SETTINGS` from your VM. If you need to download a script externally then additional firewall and Network Security Group ports need to be opened.

For more references:

- [Custom Script Extension for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows)
- [Bootstrapping Azure VMs with Terraform](http://Bootstrapping%20Azure%20VMs%20with%20Terraform)

Comment: For some reason this does not really work. I removed fileUris and just kept
"commandToExecute": "powershell.exe pwd",
"commandToExecute": "powershell.exe ls",

Comment: Error: Code="VMExtensionProvisioningError" Message="VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'grpprdad01-CSE'. Error message: \"Finished executing command\"

Comment: About this error, I suggest changing another valid fileuri to test it. Refer to [this similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54461969/azure-custom-extension-fails-with-error-messagefinished-executing-command) message.

Comment: I get the same error message but mine is Azure repo and not public git url,plus it has login credentials how can we give the PAT token to the extension along with base url for Azure devops and username?

Comment: From that document, you need to ensure VM can route to that endpoint to download the scripts, so suggest public it or store the scripts on azure storage account or download it on the local share. See the [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#additional-examples).

Comment: It appears that I may need to have the powershell script in open and not private. I created one VM in ARM and had similar issue.

Comment: Could you try to download the PowerShell scripts on a storage account, and try it again?

Comment: Or if it's the issue, you may consider accepting this answer.:)

Comment: I appreciate your efforts and the guidance you have offered me. I have accepted the answer. Answer + comments would certainly hope anyone who encounter's issue in future.

Answer (score 0):

I was hitting the same issue and eventually found it was due to the file name in blob storage having higher case letters in it! Hopefully this will help someone else avoid the same issue.